# How can achieve this with cheerio from list of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I wanted to achieve

```js
[
{
   "id": 1,
   "title":"India’s First Agriculture Export Facilitation Centre Launched in Pune",
   "date": "May 20, 2020"
}
]
```

But I am getting this.

```js
[
{
   "id": 1,
   "title":"India’s First Agriculture Export Facilitation Centre Launched in Pune",
}
]
```

I can't get the date from the `li` element.

Here is the code structure that I get

```html
<ul id="lcp_catlist" class="lcp_catlist">
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/asia-cup-2021-postponed-indefinitely-due-to-covid-19/" title="Asia Cup 2021 postponed indefinitely due to COVID-19">Asia Cup 2021 postponed indefinitely due to COVID-19</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/national-gallery-of-modern-art-launched-audio-visual-guide-app/" title="National Gallery of Modern Art launched Audio-Visual Guide App">National Gallery of Modern Art launched Audio-Visual Guide App</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/cci-approves-sale-of-yes-banks-mf-subsidiaries-to-gpl-finance/" title="CCI approves sale of YES Bank’s MF subsidiaries to GPL Finance">CCI approves sale of YES Bank’s MF subsidiaries to GPL Finance</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/west-bengal-government-approved-setting-up-of-legislative-council/" title="West Bengal government approved setting up of Legislative Council">West Bengal government approved setting up of Legislative Council</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
</ul>
```

Please help

Comment: Please add the code you are using to extract data from elements

Answer (score 0):

As `May 20, 2021` is kind of text node, not a regular element, so just use `$li.contents()` to get all the children nodes.

This should work:

```js
const markup = `
<ul id="lcp_catlist" class="lcp_catlist">
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/asia-cup-2021-postponed-indefinitely-due-to-covid-19/" title="Asia Cup 2021 postponed indefinitely due to COVID-19">Asia Cup 2021 postponed indefinitely due to COVID-19</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/national-gallery-of-modern-art-launched-audio-visual-guide-app/" title="National Gallery of Modern Art launched Audio-Visual Guide App">National Gallery of Modern Art launched Audio-Visual Guide App</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/cci-approves-sale-of-yes-banks-mf-subsidiaries-to-gpl-finance/" title="CCI approves sale of YES Bank’s MF subsidiaries to GPL Finance">CCI approves sale of YES Bank’s MF subsidiaries to GPL Finance</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
<li><a href="https://currentaffairs.adda247.com/west-bengal-government-approved-setting-up-of-legislative-council/" title="West Bengal government approved setting up of Legislative Council">West Bengal government approved setting up of Legislative Council</a> May 20, 2021 </li>
</ul>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(markup);
console.log(
  $('li')
    .map((idx, el) => {
      return {
        id: idx,
        title: $('a', el).text(),
        date: $(el).contents()[1].data.trim(),
      };
    })
    .get()
);
```

See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd0bO.png)